# How does @username commenting work?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I read in a comment that users can notify each other by starting the comment with `@username`.

1. Assume I want to notify Marco Ceppi. Do I write `@Marco Ceppi` or `@marco-ceppi`?
2. What does that user see? How is this notification shown?

Comment: I also have a "Bat Signal" at the top of the Police Station. Turn that on and I will come :D

Comment: na-na-na-na-na-na-na-na Marcoooo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments/35917#35917):

> Rules:
>
> Only applies to other people in the comments that you are commenting on, or editors of the current post.
>
> 1. Response must include @username that
>    you are referring to, where
>    "username" is a reasonable match to
>    the user's current display name (as
>    seen in the comments above yours).
> 2. There must be a starts-with, case
>    insensitive match of at least THREE
>    characters to the displayname. So @a
>    and @ab will never match anyone or
>    anything.
> 3. Spaces cannot be used to match, so
>    if the person's display name is
>    "Peter Smith" then just use @peter
>    or @petersmith to match.
> 4. Matching is performed in reverse
>    chronological order, so if there are
>    five people named "John" in the
>    comments, writing "hey @john, have
>    you considered apples?" will match
>    the most recent John to comment.

Comment: I *just* found the same answer and was coming back here to post my answer, but you beat me to it, which you seem to have a knack for :-)

Comment: @torbengb here's an example of what such a notification would look like ;)

Comment: @fluteflute, thank you for this demo -- I've updated my #2 answer accordingly!

Answer (score 6):

To answer my question #2 (based on fluteflute's helpful demonstration) the notification consists of an update in the "StackExchange" icon/menu in the top left of the page.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

There's a comprehensive (and updated from Jorge's) list at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).  I'm not quoting it here so anyone won't be tempted to not read it and thus miss updates... and so I don't have to keep this updated myself. :)